# Did all 27 other EU member states need to approve the extension of A50?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

Did all 27 other EU member states need to approve the extension of A50?

A few weeks ago there seemed to be a question mark over whether they would approve it, but this was quickly removed.

Presumably they all approved it without without question?

Answer (score 2):

> Did all 27 other EU member states need to approve the extension of A50?

Yes, through their representation in the European Council (that is, the head of state or government).

> Presumably they all approved it without without question?

Not at all.  There was a good deal of debate, apparently, about precisely how long the extension should be, and under what conditions, in particular with reference to the upcoming elections for the European Parliament.  The decision was announced after 23:00 Brussels time, after working through dinner.